# Prettify stripping Generics from C# code block

Tags: c#, prettify

I'm having a slight issue with the Prettify script that I'm trying to integrate into my website to provide intelligent syntax highlighting of C# code blocks. All works fine until I introduce Generics, which are contained within less-than and greater-than characters. Prettify seems to be completely stripping these out and replacing them with a single newline character.

Anyone have any idea how to fix this irritating behavior?

Comment: I don't think prettify is doing this.  THe examples on the prettify test page show this kind of syntax works fine. http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/prettify_test.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have no idea what the Prettify script does, it sounds like the < and > confuse the browser, because those characters are used to generate html elements.

If you want something rendered as < and > in html, you should write &lt; and &gt; (lt = less than, gt = greater than)

Answer (score 0):

Use the correct html entities to show < and >;

`&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: Aye, I just escaped the string in code tags using the HttpUtility.HtmlEncode.